# Facebook Graph API Rate limit for development

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a Facebook Application in development mode that shows as having 3 daily_active_users. From my understanding of the Graph API documentation, I can make `200 * daily active users = total request per hour`, thus, I should be able to make 600 requests per hour

I am then making a Test User and trying to create a page via the `accounts` endpoint: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/accounts/#Creating

This goes well for a single request. I then tried to script this, with 2 second timeouts in between each request, and tried to create 100 pages. After about 10 requests, I get the following response from the Facebook API: 
`{"error":{"message":"We limit how often you can post, comment or do other things in a given amount of time in order to help protect the community from spam. You can try again later. Learn More","type":"OAuthException","code":368,"error_data":{"sentry_block_data":"...","help_center_id":0},"error_subcode":1390008,"error_user_msg":"","fbtrace_id":"..."}}`.

It states that my request is being rejected due to hitting some kind of limit, but what is this limit? I can't find it in the documentation anywhere. Is there a limit to the number of pages I can create with a test user per hour/day?

Comment: Yes of course there is a limit. Why do you need that many pages for testing?

Comment: I am working on an app that allows you to publish to all your managed pages. While in development, it would be useful to be able to quickly populate a test environment so we can test features of our app without using a production/Live instance. In particular, bulk posting the same message on many pages. For example, if you are a marketing manager wanting to post the same message on all your store pages. Right now, we achieve this by manually creating pages which is very time consuming. It doesn't have to be 100 pages, that's just an arbitrary number I chose. I just want to know the limit.

Comment: You don’t get an exact number on this, otherwise any spammers would just fine-tune their apps to dance right up to that limit. (And there might perhaps not even be an exact number, easily possible that there’s some algorithms / AI applied to such decisions.)

Comment: I only need this for development and I'm using the app token for an app that has already been whitelisted by Facebook. The Facebook documentation states that limits are relaxed for test users and apps in development, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Creating 10 pages in 20 seconds seems very quick